# How could I add a named vector, only in the selected row from the data frame in R?

Tags: r, dataframe

I am trying to add on the first row of a data frame a named vector on R.

I have a code like this:

```
## Creating a named vector
obj <- 11:15
names(obj) <- c("Mobile", "Address", "City", "District", "Country")
obj
## Creating a data frame
df <- data.frame("SN" = 1:5, "Age" = c(21,15,10,31,21), "Name" = c("John","Dora", "Carlos", "Alfredo", "Joana"))
df

## Adding the vector to the data frame
i=0
for (info in obj)
{
  i = i + 1
  name = names(obj)[i]
  df[[name]][1] <- info
}
```

However, I would expect that the code above just fills the first line, but it actually fills all lines. 
[image]

**Future Work**
I want the only in the selected row, because I will have more named vectors and it will fill the other rows as well, probably inside a for.

**Expected result**

[image]

Comment: What's your expected output?

Comment: @PoGibas from the code above, I would expect only the first line to be filled and the lines [2:5] be NA Or =

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand what you're after, in your last line of the for loop, just change

```
df[[name]][1] <- info
```

to

```
df[1, name] <- info
```

The 1 could be replaced with a variable to iterate over, say, rows in a matrix that contain information you want to add row-wise to the data frame.

Comment: Thank you. It works, as you see I am a quite noob in R, just using to get the MFE library.

Comment: No worries, man. We all start somewhere. FYI, the form of indexing you originally used is more like what you would use for lists. If df was a list, df[[name]][1] would return the first element of the [[name]] item in the list. Matrices and data frames can be indexed with the [i, j] format where i is rows, j is columns. You can leave the i or j blank to index all rows and all columns respectively.

Comment: Thank you so much for the explanation, that's help a lot. It is like Python, But somehow I thought I need to put the row after the name because of the column name will be added from a variable.